# Changing 'url' property of Backbone Model and Collection

Tags: backbone.js, synchronization

I'm writing a custom `sync` for Backbone and the name `url` for the sync isn't an obvious choice. I'd like to make it something like `point` so instead of:

```
MyAppModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/some/api'
});
```

I can use...

```
MyAppModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    point: 'some/reference`
});
```

Is there any way to (without modifying Backbone) make it so `url` = `point`?

Comment: `url = function(){return this.point };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:
`url = function(){return this.point };`

But why do you want to 'rename' the `url` property? Just for semantics?

Comment: yeah, I'm referencing a connection and localstore object and url (while working) just feels odd. Hopefully it makes the script a bit less confusing